# Gitlab - Error 502 when Installing Gitlab-ce using docker-compose

Tags: macos, docker-compose, gitlab-ce

I'm working on a Mac computer. I tried to install Gitlab-ce with docker compose.

Here is the the docker-gitlab.yaml file:

```
version: '3'

services:
    gitlab:
        container_name: gitlab-ce
        restart: always
        image: gitlab/gitlab-ce:latest
        ports:
            - "8001:80"
            - "443:443"
            - "22:22"
        volumes:
            - /Users/.../GITLAB_HOME:/etc/gitlab
            - /Users/.../GITLAB_HOME:/var/log/gitlab
            - /Users/.../GITLAB_HOME:/var/opt/gitlab
```

GITLAB_HOME is a sub-folder that i created in the Users folder

When executing the next command: docker-compose -f docker-gitlab.yaml up -d
After waiting one hour, it got in the command line:

Notes:
Default admin account has been configured with following details:
Username: root
Password: You didn't opt-in to print initial root password to STDOUT.
Password stored to /etc/gitlab/initial_root_password. This file will be cleaned up in first reconfigure run after 24 hours.

NOTE: Because these credentials might be present in your log files in plain text, it is highly recommended to reset the password following https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/security/reset_user_password.html#reset-your-root-password.

When open in browser:
localhost:8001

I got the error message: 502
Whoops, GitLab is taking too much time to respond.

Could you help me to solve this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

GitLab takes time before it gets ready. This is basically an indication that it will get started within 5 minutes maximum. Are you able to access the GitLab instance now?

Incase you want to check if the GitLab is doing the migrations or not from CLI you can type:

```
docker exec -it gitlab gitlab-rails runner -e production 'puts Gitlab::BackgroundMigration.remaining'
```

This command should return “0”

```
docker exec -it gitlab gitlab-rake db:migrate:status
```

This command should return “up” for all

You can replace the name of the container , In my case my container name is "gitlab"

Comment: I run the command:
docker exec -it gitlab gitlab-rake db:migrate:status
and it returns up to all.
However, i still get the error message: 502 Whoops, GitLab is taking too much time to respond.
Do you have another idea, why it happens?
And How to solve this?

Comment: What is the output of  `docker exec -it gitlab gitlab-rails runner -e production 'puts Gitlab::BackgroundMigration.remaining'` ?